# ERROR [MailerService] Transporter is ready. Nest.js. @nestjs-modules/mailer

Tags: nestjs, nodemailer

In the terminal, an error occurs: [Nest] 21016 - 05.03.2024, 19:05:42 ERROR [MailerService] Transporter is ready. Emails are being sent. I don't know what the problem is, I need help.

The code has been checked, there are no errors.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kP2tM.jpg)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using latest version of @nestjs-modules/mailer will log this error in terminal so i'm using version 1.10.3 instead.

Comment: I am using Mailer module on local an in a docker container. Inside docker container this error appears, but not on local. I used the same env on local that I am using inside docker and it's the same thing.

Comment: The same for me, work fine on localhost, fail with "ERROR [MailerService] Transporter is ready" in docker container

Comment: For me even locally says `ERROR Transporter is redy`

Comment: Maybe it is related to Node version you are running, localhost often differs from docker container.

Comment: That's a bug in the `@nestjs-modules/mailer` indeed. There's already a fix merged into `main` but it's not released yet. Here's a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/nest-modules/mailer/issues/1131) and a [PR](https://github.com/nest-modules/mailer/pull/1121) that are related to that bug.

Answer (score 1):

Are working to fix this issue :)

https://github.com/nest-modules/mailer/issues/1131

Answer (score 1):

See the solution in this [Link](https://github.com/nest-modules/mailer/issues/1131#issuecomment-2011735557)

**Path: lib/mailer.service.ts**

```
private verifyTransporter(transporter: Transporter, name?: string): void {
const transporterName = name ?  '${name}' : '';
transporter.verify()
.then(() => this.mailerLogger.error(Transporter${transporterName} is ready))
```

❌ `.then(() => this.mailerLogger.error(Transporter${transporterName} is ready))`

**change it to**

```
 ✅.then(() => this.mailerLogger.log(Transporter${transporterName} is ready))
```

Changes:
[image for changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ownfT.png)

Output:
[Corrected Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqaUA.png)

Answer (score 0):

my version:   "@nestjs-modules/mailer": "^1.11.2",

I fixed it this way
Path: node_modules/@nestjs-modules/mailer/dist/mailer.service.js

I changed
then(() => this.mailerLogger.error(Transporter${transporterName} is ready))
to
then(() => this.mailerLogger.log(Transporter${transporterName} is ready))

Answer (score 0):

simply downgrade the latest version ( 1.11.2 ) to ( 1.10.3 )

```
npm i @nestjs-modules/mailer@1.10.3
```