npm run dev : Cannot find type definition file for 'cron'
In nest js I am facing issue for npm run dev. My machine is windows machine.
Cannot find type definition file for 'cron'.
In package.json file
{
  "name": "my-api",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 8.0",
  "yarn": "please-use-npm"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "TZ=UTC nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=development TZ=UTC nest start",
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development TZ=UTC nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "NODE_ENV=development TZ=UTC nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "NODE_ENV=production node dist/src/main"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs-modules/mailer": "^1.6.1",
    "@nestjs/common": "^9.2.1",
    "@nestjs/config": "^2.2.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^10.3.10",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^10.0.1",
    "@nestjs/mapped-types": "^1.2.2",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^10.3.10",
    "@nestjs/schedule": "^2.1.0",
    "@nestjs/serve-static": "^4.0.2",
    "@nestjs/swagger": "^7.4.0",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^10.0.2",
    "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1340.0",
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cache-manager": "^5.1.7",
    "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.14.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "ejs": "^3.1.8",
    "handlebars": "^4.7.7",
    "joi": "^17.13.0",
    "luxon": "^3.2.1",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "node-cache": "^5.1.2",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.14",
    "passport": "^0.6.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "pg": "^8.8.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^4.1.1",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.0",
    "typeorm": "^0.3.12",
    "typeorm-seeding": "^1.6.1"
  },
   "devDependencies": {
    "@faker-js/faker": "^7.6.0",
    "@nestjs/cli": "^9.1.8",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^9.0.4",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^10.3.10",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.6",
    "@types/cron": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.15",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.6",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.191",
    "@types/luxon": "^3.2.0",
    "@types/morgan": "^1.9.4",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.7",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.18",
    "@types/passport-jwt": "^3.0.8",
    "@types/passport-local": "^1.0.38",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.12",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.52.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.52.0",
    "eslint": "^8.34.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "jest": "^29.3.1",
    "prettier": "^2.8.3",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21",
    "supertest": "^6.3.3",
    "ts-jest": "^29.0.5",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.1.2",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "typeorm-seeding": {
      "typeorm": "$typeorm"
    }
  }
    }

In tsconfig.json
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"]
  }
}

When I hit npm run dev from windows machine it shows error
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'cron'.
The file is in the program because:
Entry point for implicit type library 'cron'
How can I resolve this ? Thanks in advance

I've just got an issue a couple of days ago,
and my problem is resolved by removing @types/cron in devDependencies, remove node_modules, re-build and it's works,

Thanks a lot but it shows another error
ERROR [MailerService] Transporter is ready

it's not an error, it's a bug, check it out here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78106894/error-mailerservice-transporter-is-ready-nest-js-nestjs-modules-mailer#comment137796932_78108765
